# Using getContentResolver in BroadcastReceiver extended class

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have to use the getContentResolver method in a class that extends BroadcastReceiver and I found that getContentResolver can be used only in a class that extends Activity. I try to do a static method in a class that extends activity but i can't use getContentResolver in a static method. I also tried with a non-static method but when i run the appliaction I get an error. How can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to add an event to the calendar from a class that extends broadcast receiver but my program keeps crashing. How did you get this to work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `onReceive(Context, Intent)` you receive a Context object which has a `getContentResolver()` Method.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice this until I read your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```java
ContentResolver contentResolver =context.getContentResolver();
cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```